# Getting reference error of jQuery after adding jQuery DateTimePicker (not official) in angular project

Tags: jquery, angular

In my angular project, when I didn't add jQuery DateTimePicker [Clean jQuery DateTimePicker](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker.html)

jQuery was working fine with my angular project. Here's how I have defined it in my project.

**lib.ts**

```
declare var jQuery: any;

window['jQuery'] = require('jquery');
window['$'] = window['jQuery'];
```

and using it in any component like this

**account.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'

declare var $ : any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-account',
    templateUrl: './account.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./account.component.css']
})

export class AccountComponent implements AfterViewInit {

constructor(){
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
    $(".submitBtn").click(() => {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
}

}
```

And I am not getting any error on the console. But when did I add jQuery DateTimePicker ( link on the above ) into my project.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  // Other Dependencies //

  "jquery-datetimepicker": "^2.5.20",

  // Other Dependencies //
}
```

defined it into scripts as part of `angular-cli.json`

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"
      ],
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js",
      ],
```

It started giving me error on the console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at scripts.bundle.js:2661
    at scripts.bundle.js:2663
```

In my template, jQuery DateTimePicker is working absolutely fine when we do

`$('#demo').datetimepicker({inline:true,});`

But that Reference error is still there on my console , it appears whenever I hit refresh or change any thing inside IDE.

Answer (score 3):

This will help you :

1)Install Jquery Plugin For angular

`npm install jquery --save`

2)Now in your app.module.ts add

`import * as $ from "jquery"`